# Нужна ли запятая, перед "чему"

Tags: пунктуация

*России есть чему поучиться у Крыма.*

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, поскольку **чему поучиться у Крыма** не является придаточной частью СПП.

Справочник Розенталя http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

Comment: есть чем гордиться - та же история, видимо...

Comment: Да, та же история.